# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect') - react native

Tags: ios, windows, reactjs, react-native, expo

I get this error. I am in Windows 10 and using expo sumulator in iphone 6 plus when I try to make run Camera. I try to follow the steps in this tutorial:

1 - npm install react-native-camera --save

2 - In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]

3 - Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-camera and add RNCamera.xcodeproj

4 - In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNCamera.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries

5 - Click RNCamera.xcodeproj in the project navigator and go the Build Settings tab. Make sure 'All' is toggled on (instead of 'Basic'). In the Search Paths section, look for Header Search Paths and make sure it contains both $(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React and $(SRCROOT)/../../../React - mark both as recursive.

The problem is that I am in Windows and in windows XCODE doesn't exist. How do i fix this in Windows?[image: aspect error]

Please Give to me Some help. thank you...

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View,TouchableOpacity,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

const myStyle = {
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: 'red',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
  }
};

export default class CameraAcess extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super (props);
    this.state = {hasCameraPermission: null, type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,};
}

async componentWillMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
}
render() {
    const {container,capture,preview} = myStyle;
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
        return <View/>;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 0.1, alignSelf: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center',}}
                            onPress={() => {this.setState({type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back,});}
                            }>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>{' '}Flip{' '}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'});}}
                                          style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' ,}}>[Back]</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </Camera>
            </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you rebuild your application and test it in real IOS device?

Comment: how can I rebuild the app? Can you tell me the command?

Comment: Post here the contents of your Camera.js file, it's likely an incorrect import/use.

Comment: I have edit the question and i aready add the code. Check it up an tell me what's wrong

Comment: for IOS you can run "react-native run-ios" from your root directory of project, or you can rebuild application from Xcode Ide.

Comment: @Prince I am in Expo simulator in my physical device. To run I use command in cmd windows: exp start --send-to [my phone number]. My App run in my device normaly but I get this error like in image.